# MYSQL PDO fetch multiple rows from fetchAll not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to get all the posts in wordpress using single query.

I have tried below using fetchAll(), but its not working.

It just displays `RESUlT` as many times there are total posts.

Code:

**UPDATED Helper file:**

```
$posttypevalue = Mage::helper('wordpress')->getPostMetaData();
var_dump($posttypevalue);   //gives NULL
```

**Template file**

```
public function getPostMetaData()
{
    try{
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('new_db');
    //$query = 'SELECT meta_value FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('wp_postmeta'). ' WHERE post_id = '.$postID.' and meta_key = "type"';
     echo 'vardumping results';   //Even this line is not displaying
     $query = 'SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value
                FROM wp_posts ,wp_postmeta
                WHERE  wp_posts.ID =wp_postmeta.post_id
                AND wp_postmeta.meta_key="type"
                AND wp_posts.post_status="publish"';
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    //$postdata = array();
    
    //foreach($results as $value){
        //var_dump($value);  //gives empty
        //$postdata[]=  $value['post_title'];
    //}
    }catch (Exception $e) {

        return true;
    }   
}
```

DB structure is as:

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

For the 1st query which is commented:

`$query = 'SELECT meta_value FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('wp_postmeta'). ' WHERE post_id = '.$postID.' and meta_key = "type"'`

> vardumping results
>
> `1`   displayed 5 times

For the query i am using currently:

**Output for var_dump($values):**

Empty page with header and footer.

Even the echo above the line $query doesnt display.

It very weird!!

Comment: why did you tag Magento?

Comment: because this is Wordpress fishpig magento plugin

Comment: the only difference between two queries is              wp_posts.post_status="publish"'; can you try removing it ?

Comment: still same empty page after removing the last publish condition :( and with the same condition i am able to get the output in phpmyadmin, why not in vardump? no apache logs or php logs related to this

Comment: If i do a $query= 'select * from wp_postmeta limit 5'; then i get vardump result, why not for my needed query, also i tried applying limit to my actual query, which again empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `var_dump($value)` to see the content.

I think you should use `$postdata[] = $value['post_title'];`.

The field names of the results don't contain the table name.

Comment: Yes @shawn, had tried earlier with $value['post_title'], but values are empty, also var_dump($value) is empty, but directly if i use the mentioned sql query in the phpmyadmin tool, i get results

Comment: Have you tried  `var_dump($results)`  (and paste the output to the question)? It is hard to believe that the results are empty ....

Comment: have updated the question, if i var_dump($posttypevalue); in template file, now it shows "NULL" but nothing shows if i var_dump($values)